# What is the best way to remember a successful execution over several program calls?

Tags: design, programming-practices, terminology

I'm working on a build process, that is called manually over the command line.

To check if it exited unsuccessfully during the build I want to set a lock file (symbolic link) and remove it on successful exit.

But: I don't want to rely on the existence of build files and the absence of a lock file to signal a successful build.

**Is it a good practice to just set another 'lock' if the build process was successful, that I can check for existence? If so, is there a better term for it than 'success lock'?**

Note: I'm building .iso files and they are created, whether the build process exits successfully or not.

---

Furthermore, I'm only a beginner and do not use, nor am I familiar with any industry tested frameworks or procedures. I only want to check if the files I want to "put into" the .iso file were aggregated completely. So that would be the only bit of information I require.

As the build runs locally on my machine I'm not concerned about race conditions and the like. It is merely to see, if, when repeating a build, I can immediately start putting the .iso together, or if I have to start the aggregation part over, because it didn't finish successfully.

I'm using Xubuntu Linux 14.04, but since I'm really only looking for a best practice, it shouldn't matter, I think.

Comment: Have you considered using a Continuous Integration tool like http://jenkins-ci.org/

Comment: @Mawg I'm developing the build process myself. It's not at a stage, where I would think about something like that. My question is merely about the best practice to keep track of the successful execution and a possible naming convention. Thanks for your time.

Comment: OIC, sorry (go ahead & reinvent the wheel, then ;-) Can you elaborate - will you only ever want to to remember success/fail, or might there be more data in future? Which o/s? And what if several builds are run in parallel?

Comment: @Mawg I'm afraid my question makes the whole thing seem more elaborate than it is. I added more information in the question.

Comment: "I only want to check if the files I want to "put into" the .iso file were aggregated completely" - I never yet met a CD burning or ISO creating program that did not have a "verify" option.  I am still not 100% sure of what you are doing ... multiple files --> ISO ---> verify (several times)?  Why not use existing s/w? check this I only want to check if the files I want to "put into" the .iso file were aggregated completely  or google for something like     linux create iso  command line verify

Comment: @Mawg I have several text files with file paths in them and if all those files exist and I was able to copy them into the folder, that I eventually turn into an .iso file, then I want to make that clear for the next time I call the build process. I might not make myself clear enough, when describing my project. I'm not a native speaker. But the question is really not about my specific project, but about a best practice.

Comment: Best practice is indeed having Jenkins for this. It's easy to setup and can run locally and it will save you tons of time in the future. It has large plugin support for things like failure email notification, job history tracking, etc...

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

1. Upon execution, create a temporary file and store the status in it. Useful to keep logs as well.
2. Delete the file every time new execution starts and you no longer need it.

Comment: I didn't even think about writing stuff into the file. I'm working with two locks now, like I described in my question and it works well enough.

Comment: Using locks for this is quite a strange solution. What if execution fails or some other application sets a lock on the file? It's like using a vehicle as a white board - anything can happen to your information.

Comment: I don't get the analogy, but if the execution fails, then the lock is there to signal that, so measures can be taken. So it's the whole point of it being there. And other applications would see the lock and not act on the data. Isn't that what a lock is for?

Comment: Lock is for locking files, but not to indicate success/failure of a previous job. What if some other app will lock your file - how do you know your previous execution was a failure or not?

Comment: By setting a lock, I mean creating a file (or symlink, rather) and test for its existence. I don't understand what you mean with 'locking a file'. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology?

Comment: "Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology" - either that, or I am unclear about specific terminology to your system. How does creating a file and creating a symlink sets a lock on the file? To me lock is prevention for others to use the file.

Comment: "To check if it [the process] exited unsuccessfully during the build I want to set [create] a lock file (symbolic link) and remove it on successful exit." So first thing in the process, I create the file and last thing I remove it. If something goes wrong in the middle the file is still there and serves as an indicator, that the last process did not exit successfully.

Comment: If it works for you, use it :)